# what template to choose for site collection that will have blog subsites

Tags: 2013, blog

I'm planning to create a site collection `blogs.mydomain.edu` and I'll create sub-sites using blog template for users like `blogs.mydomain.edu/namesurname` . What template should I choose for main/root site collection. Can I choose any template I want team/publishing/e.tc.? Does this template limit me for sub-sites' (blogs) features?

Comment: Give it a try, I don't think choosing Team site/publishing site will stop you from making blog subsites :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. So I created site collection as Publishing Site and sub-sites as blog. It seemed to be working fine, opening blogs to anonymous access worked too. But there was a problem. Anonymous users can't read post details. When they click to read they've asked for username and password.

This leads us to another problem described in here.

[Anonymous access for blog sites not working in SP2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7279/anonymous-access-for-blog-sites-not-working-in-sp2010)

Problem here is, as Chris described, **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** under **Site Collection Features**

This feature comes activated by default with Publishing Sites and forces visitors to login to read a blog post. After you deactivate this feature, new Blog Sub-Sites will work as expected for anonymous users. Point here is new Blogs. Blogs that are already created while this feature is active will still not function and keep asking username and password.

So create your site collection as a Blog Template.

Answer (score 2):

Their is no such restriction AFAIK, You can create the Blog Sites under Publishing site as well as team sites.

But their are other limitation i.e How many sites/subsite you are planning to create, What total size you are thinking about? As per [SharePoint 2013 Software Limit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB)

1. total number sites/subsite `250,000 per site collection`
2. If your site will go beyond 200GB then this site collection should be in own Content DB.
3. Also Keep in mind, Performance will impacted if you have tons of the Subsites and trying to delete or create new one.

Comment: Added my answer